# What will happen if two different threads(say two different https requests) try to modify/update the same key at same time in the concurrent hashmap?

Tags: java, collections

What will happen if two different threads(say two different https requests) try to modify/update the same key in the concurrent hashmap ?

Map mp = new ConcurrentHashMap();
Say, thread t1 wants to add key value pair mp.put("key", v1) & thread t2 also wants to add same key but different value mp.put("key", v2) at the same time via two different http requests then what will happen in that case ? Will it not throw any exception ?

Comment: One will happen first, that's all.

Comment: I find that a great way to answer these "What If...?"questions is to write a unit test and then just see what happens. Using `java.util.concurrent.Executors` and `CompletableFuture` should do the trick.

Comment: @jeremyt that’s not a good way for *concurrency* questions. 1) it’s hard to construct the intended scenario (“two actions being performed at *exactly* the same time”) 2) it’s even harder to verify that the scenario did actually occur (“were they *truly* performed at *exactly* the same time”) 3) the observed behavior may be an intentionally unspecified implementation detail that you won’t understand without fully understanding the specification. While, on the other hand, when you fully understood the specification, the question is moot in most cases anyway, without the need for a test.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent hashmap will lock the segment at the time of add / modify the data.
When one thread locks one segment for updation it does not allow any other thread to perform updations in same segment until lock is not released on segment.